# Read text from images in python

Tags: python, image

Is there a way for read text from an image, some kind of text recognition method using python??

I need to read some images and get the text written on them.

I have been searching libraries such as pytesser, PIL and pillow, but anyone knows something else?

For windows and python 3.6.1

Thank you,

Marcus

Comment: Maybe you find help here: http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/

Comment: It's called OCR (optical character recognition). There are many OCR programs and libraris, most of them are commercial. [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) is a Python wrapper for Google Tesseract, a free OCR.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Vision API might help. It is able to pull out what objects are present in an image as well as other information (brands, colors, face detection etc). It can pull out text pretty reliably too.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Here is some example code from their website using the Python Client Library:

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision

# Instantiates a client
vision_client = vision.Client()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources/wakeupcat.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
    image = vision_client.image(
        content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
labels = image.detect_labels()

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```